# French Math Book PDF that is easy to translate

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-french

I have to take a french proficiency exam for my grad program and I need to provide a french math book from which my exam coordinator will choose two pages for me to translate.

I was hoping for some help locating a pdf online of a french book on some undergrad level math. Something on Real Analysis, Group Theory, Calculus, or Elementary Linear Algebra would be good.

I've tried just googling and I haven't really found any free pdfs.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Most books of that sort I know are either lecture notes (not official books, but written by a prof for his class) or for-profit books meant to prepare for exams (e.g., baccalauréat). Would the former be enough for your purpose?

Comment: I believe so, as long as it is 100 or more pages.

Comment: Try the books by [Roger Godement](http://godement.eu/site/) for instance. No free pdf though.

Comment: There is [this preprint](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jean.saint-raymond/preprints/M360.pdf) by Saint-Raymond, for instance. (See also [his book](http://www.amazon.fr/Topologie-calcul-diff%C3%A9rentiel-variable-complexe/dp/2916352074).)
(*Topologie et Calcul Différentiel*, Jean Saint Raymond. (LM360, UPMC))

Comment: Not really undergrad level math but probably quite easy to read: *Uniformisation des surfaces de Riemann, retour sur un théorème centenaire*. There is a link to a free pdf at the bottom of http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/collective/. Also here: http://www.lcdpu.fr/livre/?GCOI=27000100107890&fa=complements.

Comment: Not sure it corresponds to your needs, but the pdf of the book [Mathématiques et Informatique: Problèmes résolus](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eberstel/MathInfo/MathInfos.html) is freely available.

Answer (score 2):

You could just go to to your University library and try finding Grothendieck's *Éléments de géométrie algébrique*, which has not been translated from the original French and provides plenty of practice.

As to why your Google searching has not been going well, you have probably been trying to Goggle French Math textbooks in English, which will get you English results. Google what you want (field of Math, textbook name, etc) in French with 'pdf' and you will get many results. For example:

[Cours d’analyse](http://math.unice.fr/~pauly/ca1.pdf)

[ANALYSE MATHEMATIQUE](http://www.anmath.ulg.ac.be/js/ens/am.pdf)

[Analyse
Mathématique I](https://math.umons.ac.be/an/fr/enseignement/analyse/Analyse.pdf)

[EQUATIONS DIFFERENTIELLES
METHODES DE RESOLUTION NUMERIQUE](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~sylvie.delabriere/EqDiff/ED.pdf)

[Cours de Mathematiques 2](http://les.mathematiques.free.fr/pdf/ch3.pdf)

Perhaps also try Googling 'language proficiency exams math graduate french practice' or the like and see what comes along.

Comment: The OP writes:  " a pdf online of a french book on some undergrad level math." Are you sure Grothendieck-Dieudonné's EGA satisfies the requirement ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg The links I gave are just that. I only recommend Grothendiecks book not on the basis that the material is undergraduate, but in that despite not being able to follow the Math, if one wants to claim mathematical French reading proficiency, one should be able to read through the book with a general understanding of what is being said - again, not necessarily the Mathematics. It is also an easily accesible large amount of French mathematics available in 'most' Universities mathematics library.